# Git failed with the fatal error. The requested URL return URL 400

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new to azure devops.

> I want to clone my repository to Visual studio 2017. When I try to
>   clone it it throws error. please suggest on this. I am able to connect
>   to the repository however not able to clone it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have space in the project name?

Comment: yes I have space in project name

Comment: I assume this is the problem, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Team Explorer, underneath the Clone Repository section, notice how the top box does have spaces in the URL. Cancel the clone by clicking the Cancel link. Do this, because you'll find that you cannot edit the Clone Repository inputs.
Click the Clone Repository link in the Project section of the Team Explorer window.

You'll notice the Clone Repository section will reappear, but now will not be editable. Notice that the first/top input box has replaced any spaces in the URL with %20. Ensure that you're the second box, which maps a local path to download your source to, is accurate. Click the Clone button, and it should

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have a space in your project name, if you can't rename the project, you have 2 workarounds:

**First workaround**

- In Team Explorer, underneath the Clone Repository section, notice how the top box does have spaces in the URL. Cancel the clone by clicking the Cancel link. Do this, because you'll find that you cannot edit the Clone Repository inputs.
- Click the Clone Repository link in the Project section of the Team Explorer window.
- You'll notice the Clone Repository section will reappear, but now will not be editable. Notice that the first/top input box has replaced any spaces in the URL with %20. Ensure that you're the second box, which maps a local path to download your source to, is accurate. Click the Clone button, and it should work.

**Second workaround**

- Use a browser to navigate to the 'Code' repository in Azure DevOps
- Click on the 'Clone' button (icon)
- Select IDE 'Clone in Visual Studio'
- Allow the link to open VS 2017 and it will pass along the correct URL encoded location